# GFCI and 2 phase input

Tags: gfci

[image: gfci]
[image: gfci2]
In the US, there are two phases that is 120V each to neutral. If you connect it phase to phase, then you get 240V. In my country. It's illegal to use phase to neutral of 120V because we are promoting our local products which run at 240V only (to avoid buying stuff from US). Hence are only allowed to use phase to phase of 240V.

Now I just bought a 240V Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter. A normal line to neutral GFCI would have current flowing from line to neutral. But in my case, it's 2 phases without neutral. So can the GFCI still work?

How does the current flow in phase to phase connection versus phase to neutral? Are they the same?

Comment: Can you add some details about this GFCI?

Comment: see updated post above with front and back pictures

Comment: Where on this planet *are* you?! The Philippines?

Comment: yup.. when the US colonized us.. they left us with their power system.. but after Indepedence Day we were not allowed to tap phase to neutral (120 volts) or jail time.. we are only allowed to tap phase to phase or 240 volts.. so how does the current of phase to neutral and phase to phase differ?

Comment: So what is the easiest way to test if the GFCI above would work? I don't want to use complicated resistors.. a light bulb would do. All I know if that if there is difference between the current flowing from L1 to L2, it will trigger the GFCI.. so how do you partially transfer some current from either L1 or L2 to the soil (because we never use ground in my country hence my home has no ground wire.. only 2 wire as in standard in most homes here).

Comment: The easiest way is to read the answer(s) to your question.

Comment: You mean connecting the bulb to soil would work? But if the GFCI outlet is in top floor, can't use soil. I need something handheld where I can test if the unit works. In the Philippines, it's our only protection since we don't use grounding. You will read in the following url people here quite perplexed how to use the ground  https://www.philippines-expats.com/topic/29039-grounding-of-electric-appliances/?page=4   and people are dropping up dead.. quote: "Aah the Philippines wiring ! Just this Tuesday we were told one of the wifes old friends died from an electric shock from a rice cooker !"

Answer (score 3):

GFCI's don't care.

GFCI has no relationship with ground.  They don't care if the two wires are line-line or line-neutral.  In fact your GFCI's labeling reflects that.

Also that is not 2-phase, it is single-phase with center ground.

You didn't mention you are in the Philippines.  You don't have neutral, unless you are in the US-built territories that are still officially split-phase with a 3-wire feed from the transformer.  If you are only getting 2 wires off the pole, the thing in the middle is only your ground rod, and it is definitely not made for returning current.  If you try to hook a 120V load line-ground, in the Philippines, you will only electrify all your house's grounds.

Also, using a step-down  autotransformer in the Philippines is a bad, bad idea.  Both 120V outputs will be hot, and it will be very important that you get grounding right.  In the Philippines you need an isolating transformer.

Comment: I have 3 wire coming to the service entrance.. the 3rd wire is the neutral which gets feed back to the pole transformer center tap. When I measure one of the phases to neutral, it's 120V, when phase to phase, it's 240V. That's how the 240V came from. We never use 120V. Only 240V.  About using step-down autotransformer with this setup and both 120V outputs being hot. How does this differ to the US where the autotransformer takes a phase and neutral?  This is why I asking what was the difference between phase to phase and phase to neutral in terms of current, etc.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84685/discussion-on-answer-by-harper-gfci-and-2-phase-input).